# Querying data from one database collection and saving to another database collection Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a main database and want to create a collection in the sub database that contains the result queried from the main database. I have implemented the following code. I could establish connection but for some reason, I could not find the conn_temp database and also after manually creating the database, I could not find the temp collection

```
const fs = require('fs');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var random = require('randomstring');
var main = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/communication');
var sub = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/comm_temp');

var User =  main.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    campaignResponse: Object,
    contactResponse: Object,
    uuid: String,
    retailer: Object,
}));

var temp = sub.model('Temp', new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String
}));

User.find().exec(function(err, users){
    if(err)
        throw err;
    else
    {
        temp.create(users, function(err, results){
            if( err)
                throw err;
            else {
                console.log(results);   
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use separate file for each connection, you are sharing same mongoose object, may be this would be the reason.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue.